# Implement onScrollChanged Event

Tags: android

I have an `AbsoluteLayout` xml:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/MeasureAbsLayout"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/MeasureImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ImageView>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Previous" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/MeasurePrev"           
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </Button>

        <Button android:text="Result"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/MeasureResult"         
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I want to implement `AbsoluteLayout`'s `onScrollChanged` in my `Activity` class.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to draw lines and rectangles on my screen when i drag lines using my fingers. I have already implemented the code for that.

But i am facing the problem when i zoom in my image, i do not get exact points of x and y coordinate. so for that i need to implement the onscrollchanged() event. and based on MotionEvent i can get the x and y coordinate. When i add the x, y cordinate point in current vertical and horizontal values of onscrollchanged event.